# What is .apt_generated folder in Web project?

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, war, rad, ear

What and why `.apt_generated` folder is created inside the Web Project within Eclipse or RAD workspace?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It's for holding code generated by [annotation processors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/apt/GettingStarted.html#AnnotationProcessor).

Comment: Thanks Laurence. Does that mean this folder is auto generated only for projects using annotations?

Comment: That I do not know, but I suspect it may be true as none of my Eclipse projects contain this folder.

Comment: This isn't necessarily needed for Annotations themselves.  This folder is created if and only if you have "Annotation Processing" enabled on the project.  See Project Properties > Java Compiler > Annotation Processing.  You can probably disable it if you have no classes implementing com.sun.mirror.apt.AnnotationProcessor.

Comment: I don't have "Annotation Processing" enabled, try to remove it, from the Build Path, from the project, but then it is again generated automatically. I do not use Annotations either